# How do IIS threads handle http requests & non-http requests (background jobs)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7.5

i have a question on how IIS handle requests for web application and mainly for asp.net mvc.
now let say i have the following action method , which can be called from a user browser :-

```
Public ActionResult Test (string test, string test2)
{
var a = context.singleOrDefault(a=>a.ID =test);
var b = context.Table.tolist();
a.Name="NewName";
var b = context.SingleOrDefault(a2=>a2.ID = test2)
b.status = "active";
context.SaveChanges();
return View();
}
```

now when a user calls the action method as follow:-

```
https://servername/controllername/Test?test=1&test2=2
```

will this be the IIS execution scenario ??:-

1. one of the available IIS threads will handle the request.
2. the same thread will populate the value value for var a , and execute all the operations , save changes & return the view
3. the iis thread will be released.

second question. now let say instead of calling this action method from the browser, i am calling this action method from the `global.asax` file on a timely basis as follow:-

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        static void ScheduleTaskTrigger()
        {
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("ScheduledTaskTrigger",
                                  string.Empty,
                                  null,
                                  Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
                                  TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), 
                                  CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
                                  new CacheItemRemovedCallback(PerformScheduledTasks));

        }

static void PerformScheduledTasks(string key, Object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
        {



            HomeController h = new HomeController();
           var c = h.Test("1","2");// 
            ScheduleTaskTrigger();
        }
```

so in this case will IIS be involved  in the action method execution?, as when i am calling the action method from the `global.asax` there will not be any Request,, so does this mean that iis will not get affected ? in other words no IIS thread will be occupied when i call an action method from `global.asax`? or since the web application is deployed under IIS so also background jobs' executions will still happen inside IIS threads ?

Comment: You're abusing the MVC architecture if you call an action method from `global.asax` to perform a task. You're using Hangfire, as I can see from your other questions. Stick with that or a similar technology to do your background jobs. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @mason no i am asking different things here , i am not trying to replace this with hang-fire or a scheduler tool  !! i am just asking to know if calling any method without having an http request will be done through iis or not? this is completly different question ..

Answer (score 1):

If you call a controller's action method from within .NET code, the call doesn't go out to IIS and back into .NET. No HTTP is involved. It's no different than any .NET method calling any other .NET method.

Comment: so generally speaking calling a method (action method or any other method) will have better performance and scalability when called in the background compared to being called from the user browser ?is this correct ?. i am asking this because in my case i did a test and there was a huge performance differences when the method is being called from the global.asax compared to being called form a user browser. and i was not sure why ,, but seems that the IIS might get busy when i am calling the action method from my end compared to calling it from the global.asax file .. does this sound valid ?

Comment: @johnG I don't know about "huge". But there would definitely be *some* overhead associated with the HTTP Request and Response, populating User and Session variables etc. In ASP.NET 5 (which is currently in beta) they've done a lot of work to trim down that pipeline so that the overhead penalty is much smaller.